# Displaying an image within an applet

Tags: java

I have the following code. While it displays the lines, rectangle, oval, and string correctly the image does not load. The image is in the correct directory, just cannot figure out why it isn't displaying...

```
import java.awt.*;  // for Graphics, Image, and Color classes
import java.applet.Applet;

public class GraphicsDemo extends Applet
{

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        Image image;
        image = this.getImage(getDocumentBase (), "flower.jpg");

        // display smaller complete image in upper left corner of window
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 427, 284,      // destination topL, botR
                0, 0, 640, 427, this);      // source topL, botR

        // establish color of all lines to be drawn
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        // draw rectangle around region to be expanded
        g.drawRect(200, 60, 120, 120);          // topL, width & height

        // draw lines between corners of rectangles
        g.drawLine(200, 60, 240, 240);          // upper left
        g.drawLine(320, 60, 600, 240);          // upper right
        g.drawLine(200, 180, 240, 600);         // lower left
        g.drawLine(320, 180, 600, 600);         // lower right

        // display expanded part of original image
        g.drawImage(image, 240, 240, 600, 600,  // destination topL, botR
                300, 90, 480, 270, this);   // source topL, botR

        // draw rectangle around expanded part of image
        g.drawRect(240, 240, 360, 360);         // topL, width & height

        // create BLUE colored oval and write name on it
        g.fillOval(520, 380, 45, 30);           // topL, width & height
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);            // change color for text
        g.drawString("Max", 530, 400);          // string & start position

    }   // end main
}   // end class GraphicsDemo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely the image does not exist in the document base. The rest of the code is functionally ok. Add the an init method as follows:

```
public void init() {
    System.out.println(getDocumentBase());
}
```

and copy the image there to the location displayed.

---

Some related notes:

You're missing this statement from `paint`

```
super.paint(g);
```

Also would suggest moving this statement

```
image = this.getImage(getDocumentBase (), "flower.jpg");
```

to the applet's `init` method so that the image is not being loaded every time the applet is painted.